# Ruby reading file content from GSC bucket without downloading the actual file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, google-cloud-storage

I am quite new to Google Cloud Storage. I want to read the CSV file content form the GCS bucket and get the single column data that too without downloading the actual file. I have tried this and got the column data after downloading and then reading the file content.

Answer (score 1):

The API of `google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob specifies` that the `download_as_string` method has `start` and `end` keywords that provide byte ranges:

ref: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob

In ruby there is one issue is create for the same to read specified bytes
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/1356

You need to check its implemented or not but yes Its Do able